# Exponential complex network under random attack

Tags: python, graph, networkx, complex-networks

I'm trying to simulate a random attack on an Erdos-Renyi network. The supposed result is that the network collapses when you remove aproximately 20 to 30% of the nodes. However, I can't reproduce that result, as the size of the giant connected component seems to decreases linearly.

```
import networkx as nx
import random as rd

def random_single():
    l1 = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(1000, 0.01)
    nodes = []
    gcc = []
    n_nodes = l1.number_of_nodes()
    removed_nodes = 0

    gcc_size = len(list(max(nx.connected_components(l1), key=len))) / n_nodes
    gcc.append(gcc_size)
    nodes.append(0.0)

    while l1.number_of_nodes() > 1:

        node = rd.choice(list(l1.nodes()))
        l1.remove_node(node)
        removed_nodes += 1

        gcc_size = len(list(max(nx.connected_components(l1), key=len))) / n_nodes
        gcc.append(gcc_size)
        nodes.append(1 - ((og_n_nodes - removed_nodes) / n_nodes))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(nodes, gcc)
```

Expected result:

[image]

My result:

[image]

Comment: Any reason your result has a flipped horizontal axis (i.e. values 0.0 to +1.0 from right to left)?

Answer (score 0):

In your Expected result picture, it seems that failure situation and the attack situation cause the same result, it's really a little bit strange. In the real world, the random attack impact on the network is relatively slow. I do not think your result is wrong.